# Make a .sty file available to all tex files one level below in the directory tree?

Tags: packages

I have a directory `/home/me/Documents/LabReports/`, under which I have multiple directories for each of my documents: `.../LapReports/report1/`, `.../LabReports/report2/`. What should I do if I want to make a style file, `reportstyle.sty`, "globally" accessible to all .tex files in each of these `report1`, `report2`, etc. directories? *without having to copy and paste* the `reportstyle.sty` file into each directory? I want to be able to acccess it using `\usepackage{}` using something like
`\usepackage{../reportstyle}` if that makes sense:

```
/home/me/Documents/LabReport/
    + reportstyle.sty <--------------------------|
    + report1/                                   |
        + doc.tex <-- \usepackage{reportstyle}---|
    + report2/                                   |
        + doc.tex <-- \usepackage{reportstyle}---|
    + ....
```

I do not want to add it to the TEXMF path because (1) I wont really be needing it after the reports are done and (2) it would be convenient to have all related files contained within `LabReports/` so I can move all of it at once to another disk. Is there any builtin way of doing this ? or should I just symlink `reportstyle.sty` to every `report.../` directory?

Comment: You can simply create a symlink in the TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/ directory to your .sty file.

Comment: What is wrong with simply supply the relative path, i.e., `\usepackage{../reportstyle}`?